# Undefined reference use automake

Tags: c, makefile, automake

My project structure like this

```
-myProject
    -Makefile.am
    -configure.ac
    -src
        -Makefile.am
        -add.c
        -add.h
    -tests
        -Makefile.am
        -tests.c
```

Makefile.am

```
SUBDIRS = src tests
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
```

src / Makefile.am

```
AM_CFLAGS = -Wall -lcunit -nostartfiles 
bin_PROGRAMS = addNum
addNum_SOURCES = add.c
addNum_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)
```

src / add.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "add.h"

int addNum(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

tests / Makefile.am

```
AM_CFLAGS = -Wall -lcunit

INCLUDES = -I$(top_srcdir)/src -I../src 

noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libsrc.la
libsrc_la_SOURCES = -I$(top_srcdir)/src
libsrc_la_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)


bin_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = tests.c
test_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)
test_LDADD = libsrc.la
```

tests / tests.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "add.h"

int main(void){
    printf("num:%d",addNum(1,1));
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
tests.c:6: undefined reference to 'addNum'
```

I try to include addNum function in tests/tests.c.
Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: Where do you run the build?  In the top-level directory, or in the `tests` sub-directory. I'm not sure where the code in `tests/Makefile.am` says "make sure `../lib/libsrc.la` is built before linking `test`.  I'm not even sure where the code in `src/Makefile.am` says "build `libsrc.la`" either.  And, in general, it is a good idea to avoid the command name `test` because it is also a shell built-in and testing your test program (that is, testing `test`) can be error prone as a result.

Comment: I build project in top-level. `libsrc.la` that is create by myself .I doesn't know  how to include src source file ,so i try to use `libsrc.la` to link `test`.

Comment: how to do to link source file to test in other project?

Comment: I haven't used `automake` in a multi-directory project; I'm not sure what you need to do — other than read the manual carefully and/or find a project that exemplifies what you're trying to do that you can copy the ideas from.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank  you answer for me. ctheo's answer is helpful.

Comment: Please read "[Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/)" and consider following its advice.  It's not a big deal *now*, but when your project gets bigger you will be much happier if you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort version answer is to change

```
libsrc_la_SOURCES = -I$(top_srcdir)/src
```

to

```
libsrc_la_SOURCES = -I$(top_srcdir)/src/add.c
```

Meaning that you need to define the list of sources need by `libsrc.la` library.

But I think that you would better follow the steps of the long version answer.
I guess you try to create a `libsrc.la` binary from a list of sources in `src` directory and then link this binary with a set of tests. So first you need to create the library inside `src` directory.

src/Makefile.am

```
AM_CFLAGS = -Wall -lcunit
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libsrc.la
libsrc_la_SOURCES = add.c
libsrc_la_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)
```

Then link your tests with this library.

tests/Makefile.am

```
AM_CFLAGS = -Wall -lcunit
INCLUDES = -I$(top_srcdir)/src -I../src 
bin_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = tests.c
test_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)
test_LDADD = ../src/libsrc.la
```